# OSX-Terminal -jar run command

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, coderunner

I used to work with Eclipse but switched recently to CodeRunner. The Problem is I'm supposed to use Graphviz, Batik and a Package from my college in order to work on some projects.

As long as there was one .jar file I'll managed to use my own with a simple:

```
RunCommand: java -jar stopndrop.jar $compiler
```

Arguments:

$1 Filename of the source file

$2  Encoding of the source file

$3  Compilation flags set in CodeRunner

$4  Path of a temporary directory

```
javac "$1" -d "$4"/java-compiled -encoding ${enc[$2]} $3 -cp stopndrop.jar
```

But now there is the Batik and College Folder with a bunch of Classes that are supposed to be loaded when they r needed.

My Question is: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have the following folder structure:

```
lib/
    a.jar
    b.jar
classes/
    com/
        foo/
            Bar.class
            Baz.class
```

And you need to link with all of these things to compile some code.  Then you would specify as your classpath:

```
-cp lib/a.jar:lib/b.jar:classes
```